# MockMvc JsonPath skipping a prefix

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, mockmvc

I couldn't a find a solution for that issue yet...
Basically I would like to test some rest resources that produce a json response, the json is prefixed by a security string, for example:

`"qwerty{"status":"success"}"`

of course with the prefix this is not a valid json, hence the json path fail:

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/myresource")
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andDo(print())
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.status").value("success"))
```

with the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **Invalid container object**  at
>   com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:180)  at
>   com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:211)  at
>   org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.evaluateJsonPath(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:98)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.assertValue(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:115)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.JsonPathResultMatchers$2.match(JsonPathResultMatchers.java:68)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:152)

Are there a way to skip a given prefix and let the jsonpath works properly? Maybe with a global configuration?

**EDIT** to clarify the case, the prefix is declared in the jackson http message converter:

```
@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    converter.setPrefixJson(true);
    converter.setJsonPrefix("qwerty");
    return converter;
}
```

**Edit** [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13577) the link to the related jira issue

Comment: I don't know if you can configure JsonPath to do this, so you may be better off using `MvcResult result = mockMvc.perf/**snip**/.andReturn();`, parsing the JSON via Jackson (after trimming the prefix), and using asserts to do the same validations that JsonPath would have given you.

Comment: could you open an issue on https://jira.spring.io? This looks like a valid feature request!

Comment: @xathien yes I could but I would prefer keeping a more clean and elegant way :)

Comment: @BrianClozel sure, I'll open it

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Unfortunately, we just missed the latest 4.2.x release window.